# Laravel RefreshDatabase doesn't work in testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5

In order to move my current Laravel 5.5 project to the latest version, I was trying to setup some tests (I've never done that before).

To do so, I added `<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing" />` in the `phpunit.xml`, under the `<php>` section, and created a copy of the current `mysql` configuration under `config/database.php` naming it `mysql_testing`, which has `'database' => env('DB_NAME_TESTING', 'forge')` .

In the `.env` file I put `DB_NAME_TESTING=testDB`. The database exists, is empty and the user has all permissions on it.

I haven't created any Test, yet, just tried the Examples provided by Laravel. If I run the tests as they are, they all pass. If I add the `RefreshDatabase` trait on them, instead, I get

```
ErrorException : Trying to access array offset on value of type int
C:\[path to project]\vendor\symfony\console\Input\ArrayInput.php:135
```

which corresponds to  `} elseif ('-' === $key[0]) {`.

After a bit of tracing, I found out that the `$key` is `'migrate:fresh'`, which is the Artisan command that `RefreshDatabase` is trying to run. In later versions this segment has been replaced with `} elseif (str_starts_with($key, '-')) {`, but this is only available since PHP 8, and I'm currently stuck with PHP 7.4.

My question now is: what am I doing wrong in setting up my testing database?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Laravel 9 using PHP 7.4. Take a look at [Support policy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#support-policy) - max version for PHP 7.4 is Laravel 8 so either use newer PHP version or upgrade to Laravel 8 and not Laravel 9.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong: I'm trying to setup the tests using Laravel 5.5, before upgrading to Laravel 9, in order to check everything works before and after the upgrade. I'm currently working on Laravel 5.5 and PHP 7.4. When I will move the project it will be on Laravel 9 and PHP 8.something. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Cynical You clearly wrote that you use code that uses `str_starts_with` which does not exist in PHP 7,4 so you cannot use that code

Comment: Nabialek I clearly wrote that the line causing the error is `('-' === $key[0])`, which has __later__ been replaced with `str_starts_with` in subsequent releases, but I currently am working on Laravel 5.5, on PHP 7.4.